# CSS Link to stylesheet stopped formatting

Tags: html, css

Embedding my css file is usually fairly simple for me,

*I'm far from well versed in CSS but I am not just writing a question without first trying to fix it myself for hours.*

However for this project, I had all my css internally written.

```
<style> </style>
```

Once I started to transfer all my CSS to my stylesheet all my formatting has disappeared.

My GitHub repo is

https://github.com/marcoantonio123456/Studio

The site itself is being deployed at

https://marcoantonio.netlify.com

**Issue was resolved, error was from the imported fonts, Thank you to the community :)**

Comment: you could provide more details of what exaclty did you do

Comment: I took all the CSS code from inside the index.html file to the style.css . In the process the CSS code stopped working. I removed all the <style> tags and it was working for a few test runs but as I debugged it and added more content to the site. It stopped working

Comment: Please include a [mre] in the question itself. Since this is about HTML and CSS, you may be able to use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552), but since you're talking about moving to an external style sheet it might not work. The basic debugging here is to revert to a version of the site before the transfer and ensure everything works. Then, move things one rule at a time until it fails.

Comment: You are 100% right, I am currently using http://csslint.net to go line by line on the code to see where I went wrong. The stylesheet is just a style.css file in the same directory as index.html

Comment: If you look at your CSS file on github, it actually syntax highlights it for you and you can see the syntax errors. https://github.com/marcoantonio123456/Studio/blob/master/style.css More at: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: Thank you! Will report after I found the bug.

Comment: Thank you Jan! I solved the issue was in the import of fonts. Will push the to GitHub once I am happy with the CSS. Please post your suggestion as an answer  so I can have my question answered

Comment: Edits pushed! Thanks Jan